# How do you findIndex with conditionals like &&

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

Let's say you have a List l_mur = new List();

And you populate the list.

Then based on conditions you want to REMOVE some values without requerying...

```
l_mur.RemoveAt(l_mur.FindIndex(f => (f.xid == tmur.xid && f.sid == tmur.sid && f.mid == tmur.mid && f.bid == tmur.bid)));
```

However, the code I used here, does not seem to work. It tells me index out of range, but how can it be out of range if I am just searching for something that truly does exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>.FindIndex()` returns -1 in case there is no match found - which is out of range for `List<T>.RemoveAt()`.

Also note that `FindIndex()` only returns the index of the *first* occurrence based on your predicate - if there is more than one match you will only be able to delete the first one of them with your current approach.

A better approach to delete in place based on a predicate would be `RemoveAll()`:

```
l_mur.RemoveAll(f => (f.xid == tmur.xid && f.sid == tmur.sid && f.mid == tmur.mid && f.bid == tmur.bid));
```

Answer (score 1):

May be a good idea is to filter the list to a new instance of the list:

```
var l_mur = l_mur.Where(f => (f.xid != tmur.xid || f.sid != tmur.sid || f.mid != tmur.mid || f.bid != tmur.bid));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
l_mur.Remove(l_mur.Find(f => (f.xid == tmur.xid && f.sid == tmur.sid && f.mid == tmur.mid && f.bid == tmur.bid)));
```